# Materialized view rebuild fails on Cloudera Data Platform

Tags: sql, hive, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, materialized-views

I have created a materialized view called `my_mat_view1` in a hive database on a Cloudera cluster (Cloudera Data Platform Version 7.1.7), that I am attempting to periodically rebuild using the sql command:

```
 ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW my_database.my_mat_view1 REBUILD;
```

When I run this command on yarn, using beeline, I get the error:

`Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Another process is rebuilding the materialized view my_database.my_mat_view1 (state=42000,code=40000)`

I have checked to see that there are no yarn applications accessing the materialized view and there are no locks on the table according to, `SHOW LOCKS my_database.my_mat_view1`. I have tried to `DROP`, `CREATE`, and then `REBUILD` the materialized view and get the error as well. Strangely enough rebuilding a different materialized view (`my_mat_view2`) does work. Both materialized views have a large number of partitions (20k) and consist of a subset of data of a larger table.

I was wondering if anyone knows how it is determined whether a materialized view is being rebuilt? Could there be a temporary file that needs to be cleaned up?